# Periodic server status checking on several servers concurrently

Tags: c#, .net

First of all, My English is poor. Please understand me.

My small project is concurrently Checking several server statuses with C# .NET.

My Question is; do I have to make several `Timer` and operate each of them with `Thread.start()` or do I have to make Several `Thread` and each Thread should operate `Timer.start()` ?

If both of two are not a proper method, please teach me how to do this..
Examples are always welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use System.Threading.Timer, it will take care of the threading for you. From the documentation:

> Use a TimerCallback delegate to specify the method you want the Timer
>   to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is
>   constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the
>   thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread
>   supplied by the system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Like the documentation says: "The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system". You'll set up your timers and the callbacks will be executed on separate threads from the ThreadPool.